# $xy''-y=0$ with initial conditions $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=1$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $xy''-y=0$ with $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=1$

Hello! I'm currently working on this problem in my differentials course and I've come up on an issue..

My solution utilizes the Frobenius method and I found the two roots of the indicial equation to be $1$ and $0$.

Given this I solved for my two solutions but one of my linearly independent solutions looks like this 
$$y(x)=ay_1(x)\log(x) + \sum b_nx^n$$
I'm not sure how to apply these initial conditions as $\log(0)$ is undefined, any help would be appreciated

$$y_1(x)=x\sum a_n(-1)^n\frac{x^n}{(n+1)!\,n!}$$

Comment: I think this indicates that none of the solution pass through $y(0)=0$ with $y'(0)=1$.

Comment: The first linearly independent solution does pass through these points, I have the solution to it but I am unsure how to format it completely

Comment: I have included $y_1$ in the equation, sorry if the notation is not the best I hope it is relatively clear

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=xy%27%27%E2%88%92y%3D0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer to the question, just for information. Too long to be edited in the comment section.

$$xy''-y=0$$
is an ODE of the Bessel kind.

It is easy to find the general solution in terms of Bessel functions :
$$y(x)=c_1\sqrt{x}I_1(2\sqrt{x})+c_2\sqrt{x}K_1(2\sqrt{x}) \quad\text{if}\quad x>0$$
$$y(x)=c_1\sqrt{-x}J_1(2\sqrt{-x})+c_2\sqrt{-x}Y_1(2\sqrt{-x}) \quad\text{if}\quad x<0$$
$J_1,Y_1$ are the first order Bessel function of first and second kind. $I_1,K_1$ are the first order modified Bessel function of first and second kind.

Case $x>0$:

The series expansion for $x\to 0^+$ is :
$$y(x)=c_1\left(x+\frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^3)\right)+c_2\left(\frac12+\frac12(\ln(x)+2\gamma-1)x+O\left(x^2\ln(x)\right) \right)$$ 
Thus, the condition $y(0)=0$ implies $c_2=0$ and then :
$$y(x)=c_1\left(x+O(x^2)\right)$$
$$y'(x)=c_1\left(1+O(x)\right)$$
The condition $y'(0)=1$ implies $c_1=1.$
So, the solution is :
$$y(x)=\sqrt{x}I_1(2\sqrt{x})\qquad x>0$$
Similarly, one obtains :
$$y(x)=\sqrt{-x}J_1(2\sqrt{-x})\qquad x<0$$

This functions expressed on the form of series agree with the result already given in the preceding answers.

Answer (score 0):

That formula should be $$y_1(x)=x\cdot a_0\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^n}{(n+1)!n!},$$ 
as you replace all $a_n$ in $y_1(x)=\sum a_nx^n$ with multiples of $a_0$.

Accidentally the first initial condition is automatically satisfied ($y(0)=1$ would be impossible for any solution) and with $a_0=1$ you also get the second one.